# as3: How to create a custom iterator

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create custom iterator element. The class itself is below.

```
    public class ArrayBasedIterator implements IteratorInterface
{
    // Holds Array of elements which are iterated
    private var _container:Array;

    // Holds current index
    private var _index:uint = 0;

    public function ArrayBasedIterator(data:Array)
    {
        if (!data) 
               throw new Error("Cannot create iterator for null data");
        _container = data;
    }

    /**

    * Returns next node if it exists, null otherwise*/
    public function next():TreeNode
    {
        if (_index > _container.length )
        {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            _index += 1;
        }

        //TODO: implement function
        return _container[_index];
    }

    /**

    * Returns prev node if it exists, null otherwise*/

    public function prev():TreeNode
    {
        if (_index < 0)
        {
            return null
        }
        else {
            _index -= 1;
        }

        //TODO: implement function
        return _container[_index];
    }

    public function len():int
    {
        return _container.length;
    }

}
```

The question is. In case I have such iterator over some elements, would it be possible to use for .... in structure? What do I need to change to use it? (Except using just array instead of iterator of course)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing nicely with "for each" in ActionScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787289/playing-nicely-with-for-each-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `for ... in`, you'll need to subclass `Proxy` and override the appropriate methods:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html